# Filtering while HTTP is still in progress Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, filter, angularjs-filter

I got I problem and I cant wrap my head around it.

I send an http request retrieving me data from an API. This may take up to `15 seconds`. But I implemented a cache so that the user can see parts of the data already that has already arrived. Every `1500ms` I update this data. Once `data.length>0`, I show filters to the user, so that he can filter his results by price.

When he applies the filters all filters are set back to the original state after each update of the data.

```
$scope.$watch('trainRequest.getRequest()',function(newVal,oldVal){
        $scope.data = trainRequest.getRequest();
        $scope.trainArray = resultService.trainArray;


        if($scope.data.error!==1){
// here I generate the minimum and maximum price in the data that I use to show the filter.
$scope.maxValue=(function(){
            var tempArray=[];
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
              tempArray.push($scope.data[i].price); // jshint ignore:line
            }
            return tempArray.length>0 ? Math.round(Math.max.apply( Math, tempArray)) : 5000;
          })();

          $scope.minValue=(function(){
            var tempArray=[];
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
              tempArray.push($scope.data[i].price); // jshint ignore:line
            }
            return tempArray.length>0 ? Math.round(Math.min.apply( Math, tempArray)) : 0;
          })();
}
```

Here is my issue. Let's say the data provides `100$` and `1000$` as the minimum and maximum of the price array. Then my filter (a slider) moves in this interval. But Let's now say the user only accepts `800` as maxmimum price. Then he uses the slider and the data that is shown updates.

Then data updates because I receive new data from the server. Let's now say the actual maximum is `1400$`. Then the slider would range from `100` to `1400`. What aslo happens is that the slider is set to this state and I want the slider to remain at 800$ maximum.

My problem is that everytime `$scope.data` updates (because it is in the watch function and the maxValue is also there) I am not able to save the status as desired by the user.

How is it possible to only save the state of the filter if it is changed by the user and not by the update of `$scope.data`?

Answer (score 1):

You need another property in your scope e.g. `$scope.selectedMaxValue`. This property will contain the selected max value from the user. If it is different than the `$scope.maxValue` before the update, you should not change the `$scope.selectedMaxValue` if it is the same as the `$scope.maxValue` you should update it as well.

You can you this approach for the `minValue` as well.

**EDIT**: 
Here is an example of how you can do this.

You can write the following function

```
    function updateMaxValue(){
  var tempArray=[];
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
              tempArray.push($scope.data[i].price); // jshint ignore:line
            }
            var newValue = tempArray.length>0 ? Math.round(Math.max.apply( Math, tempArray)) : 5000;

    if($scope.selectedMaxValue === $scope.maxValue)
    {
        $scope.selectedMaxValue = newValue;
    }

    $scope.maxValue = newValue;
}
```

And use it like this

```
    $scope.$watch('trainRequest.getRequest()',function(newVal,oldVal){
        $scope.data = trainRequest.getRequest();
        $scope.trainArray = resultService.trainArray;


        if($scope.data.error!==1){
         // here I generate the minimum and maximum price in the data that I use to show the filter.
         updateMaxValue();

         updateMinValue();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Let me get this straight. $scope.maxValue updates every time $scope.data updates. Now I set $scope.selectedMaxValue=function(){return $scope.maxValue}. How can I check whether selectedMaxValue()===maxValue depending on an update. Sorry, it may sound stupid, but I am stuck at this point. Can you just give an example how it would work. Or how this selectedMaxValue function looks like

Comment: Looks good I guess...How do you set selectedMaxValue in the first place.

Comment: On initial load it should be set automatically. The selectedMaxValue and maxValue should be undefined, so they will be equal and the selectedMaxValue will be set to the newValue.